# What is ** in the following: int className(baseClassName** obj,int a) in C++ Polymorphism?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

```
int className(baseClassName** obj,int a)
```

What should I send to baseClassName** to make operations?

Comment: `obj` is a pointer to pointer

Comment: Suppose you had the variables `baseClassName *p, **pp;`. You could pass `nullptr`, or `&p`, or `pp` as an argument, and they would all compile. What you need to actually pass, however, depends on what `className` expects, which you provided no details on.

Comment: Please put "definitive C++ book and guide list" into the searchbar on top, there you should be able to find several tutorials that would all explain this syntax. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning you question, what to put there, it's impossible to tell because you don't say what you want to achieve. In other words, the broader context is missing.

Comment: `baseClassName** obj` is *probably* a pointer to an array of pointers to baseClassName objects.  C++ syntax does not distinguish between pointer-to-object and pointer-to-array of objects.  In C++, to support polymorphism a pointer or reference to a base class is necessary, otherwise passing by value will cause *slicing* which is (usually) a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means you have 2 indirections. Obj is pointer to pointer of `baseClassName`. As `int` is also passed I can assume that it may be the size of 2d array of pointers to `baseClassName` objects Allocated on heap.

you have to pass to this function will look like this.

```
    int size = 5;
    baseClassName** obj = new baseClassName*[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size;++i){
        obj[i] = new baseClassName[size];
    }
```

Now you can call this function like this:

```
int num = className(obj, size);
```

and yes do not for get to free your memory once you have done using it.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        delete [] obj[i];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It means pointer to pointer, and while it's fashionable to write it that way, prefer writing it as `baseClassName **obj` as this declaration:

```
baseClassName** obj, obj2;
```

suggest obj2 is a pointer to pointer but it's actually a baseClassName.